# How can I update a UIView width with a UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift-playground

I'm trying to change the width of a UIView with a slider. My problem is that instead of updating the views width my code is adding new views. I don't know how to update the view with swift playgrounds.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var feelings01Slider: UISlider!
    var feelingsWidth01 = 100

    var dayFeelings01: UIView!
    var dayFeelings02: UIView!
    var dayFeelings03: UIView!

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view

        feelings01Slider = UISlider()
        feelings01Slider.frame = CGRect(x: 62, y: 375, width: 250, height: 20)
        feelings01Slider.minimumValue = 1
        feelings01Slider.maximumValue = 248
        feelings01Slider.value = 100
        feelings01Slider.isContinuous = true

        feelings01Slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        setUpFeelings()

        view.addSubview(feelings01Slider)
    }

    func setUpFeelings() {

        feelingsWidth01 = Int(feelings01Slider.value)
        var feelingsX02 = feelingsWidth01 + 62
        var feelingsWidth02 = 80
        var feelingsX03 = feelingsX02 + feelingsWidth02
        var feelingsWidth03 = 70

        dayFeelings01 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 62, y: 100, width: feelingsWidth01, height: 250))
        dayFeelings01.backgroundColor = .yellow

        dayFeelings02 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: feelingsX02, y: 100, width: feelingsWidth02, height: 250))
        dayFeelings02.backgroundColor = .blue

        dayFeelings03 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: feelingsX03, y: 100, width: feelingsWidth03, height: 250))
        dayFeelings03.backgroundColor = .red

        view.addSubview(dayFeelings01)
        view.addSubview(dayFeelings02)
        view.addSubview(dayFeelings03)

    }

    @objc func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider) {
        feelingsWidth01 = Int(sender.value)
        dayFeelings03.removeFromSuperview()
        dayFeelings02.removeFromSuperview()
        dayFeelings01.removeFromSuperview()
        setUpFeelings()
    }


}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

I'm new to programming so excuse me if my code seems messy.

Comment: Remove an existing sub view with fast enumeration on 'view` every time you add three ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to replace the views with new, differently-sized views . You can just change their frames. Replace your slider selector action with this:

```
@objc func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider) {
    dayFeelings01.frame.size.width = CGFloat(sender.value)
}
```

Note: because the yellow view was added *first*, it is expanding *underneath* the other views. That's why you can't see it get wider. Try changing the order so it's added last and you'll see it. If you want the other views to adjust to the available space, you can update their frames too, a UIStackView might make that easy.

Good luck!